NoReverseMatch at / .Reverse for ‘login’ not found. ‘login’ is not a valid view function or pattern name
I'm currently building a website using Django and have some issues, can someone please help me with this. Here is my urls.py file:
from django.urls import path, include
from  . import views
import sys

app_name = "myapp"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('wordsearch', views.wordsearch, name='wordsearch'),
    path('generate', views.generate, name="generate")
] 

and my views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect # redirect: chuyen huong user toi page khac
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Feature
from myproject.main import *
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm

# Create your views here.
# gửi request tới thư mục templates để tìm file index.html
def index(request):
    # dictionary 
    return render(request, 'login.html')


# log in and sign up function
def register(request):  
    # check if the page is rendered with a post method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # log the user in
            return redirect('login')
    else: 
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})


def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('wordsearch')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})

# log out
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request) # log all user out of platform
    return redirect('/')

def wordsearch(request):
    return render(request, 'wordsearch.html')
    

my login.html:
<h1> Login Now </h1>

{% for message in messages %}
<h3>{{message}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\myproject\myapp\views.py", line 13, in index
    return render(request, 'login.html')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 471, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\VSC\word-search-AI\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

my main urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls'))
]

I'm confused with the error. It says login is not a valid view function though I have defined login function in my views.py. Please help me with this problem, thank you so much!

Is that the app-level urls.py? What does your main urls.py look like?

@Selcuk I have updated my main urls.py

You have specified an app_name variable in your urls.py file, which means you've namespaced your urls. So you should refer to the url as myapp:login.

@AbdulAzizBarkat, thank you, I have solve my problem, but now it says: Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.

what does your main urls.py?.
I think you have to change the name of login function
Because login function make a conflict with django builtin login function
change your function name login  to dologin

This is total nonsense.
